# Parse XLS(Excel) file in JS implementation

Tags: javascript

Good day everyone! 
Is there a JS toolkit which parse an XLS file?

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but not quite...i want to get *.xls file from ajax, and then parse it using JavaScript, not using Apache commons/etc.

Comment: You're right; there are a couple of other similar questions but the "answers" are terrible. That said, from what I know of XLS it may be hard to find a solution. It's a complicated format and, to my knowledge, it's incompletely specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you are still watching this, but I've been working on a pure JS XLS parser: http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/